# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord size on association returns twice the amount of count after duplicating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

After copying an active record object my new objects association.size returns double the amount of how many are actually in the database. I've seen that size trys to load a cached version and count actually executes a query but I don't want to always execute an SQL query just to show the amount.
My (relevant) code looks like this:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
def copy_model
 new_model = self.dup
 new_model.name = "Copy of #{name}"
 new_model.association = association.map{|a| a.dup}
 new_model.save
 new_model
end
```

after this calling .size on new_model.association returns twice the amount of .count

Comment: No, you must be doing wrong somewhere else. Count and Size, both will give the same output. Also, in your above code, their is syntax error while duplicating associations. 

Otherwise, the above code works perfectly for copying the model.

Comment: try `new_model.association.reload.count`

Comment: @MrYoshiji `count` is a query and will return an accurate result. `size` is a method call against the association "Array" if the "Array" is already `loaded?`. `size` can be different than count if it contains objects that have yet to be presisted. `count` with or without the `reload` will return the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after  Aakash Gupta and Szymon said I'm doing something wrong somewhere else I found out that my association class has this line:

```
belongs_to :model, counter_cache: :association_count
```

Which is there to make the size operator more efficient and skip database querys. However after duplicating objects my cache was corrupted. So calling:

```
Model.reset_counters(new_model.id, :association)
```

as described here: 
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters
fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that and there is nothing wrong with your code on Rails 4. Try to write Rspec like:

```
copied_model = ...
expect(copied_model.reload.association.size).to eq 3
```

Furthermore, it could be a problem when associated model is an `Image` referring to remote storage. But without further context what the `association` is, it is difficult to find a problem here.

Assuming that you know that [association](https://reservedwords.herokuapp.com/words/association) is a reserved word and you cannot use it as a custom collection name.

Comment: The Association is just another active record class. But I realized that it has this line:  `belongs_to :model, counter_cache: :association_count`
which according to documentation makes the method size more efficient. But it might also mess with the cache in my case right?

Comment: Alright edit: I did some googling and found this: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/reset_counters
reseting the counter fixed my problem. Yay! Thanks a lot of letting me look in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a map. Try the following:

```
association.each do |a| 
  new_model.association << a.dup
end
```